# Google Account to sign into a third-party website

Tags: authentication

I want to use google/yahoo ids to be used to login to my website.
As its done in stackoverflow.

Can any one provide me a starting point.

Comment: its available for php, is it available for perl too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That authentication method is called [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).  You can get details at the [open id website](http://openid.net/).

If your webiste uses PHP on the server, here's a resource to get you started with [OpenID and PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581)

*UPDATE*

Since I've posted this, the world of open federated authentication has evolved quite a bit. If you're interested in this you may wish to look up **OAuth v2** online, or check out these links: [www.oauth.net](http://oauth.net/) and the [Google resources on OAuth2 available here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).

OAuth builds upon the concepts of OpenID and it expands the functionality quite a bit, in particular in the areas of not just providing authentication but also providing authorization for applications using a centralized provider of the user's choice (i.e. Google, Facebook, Twitter or your own :) )

Comment: Some further info specific to logging in with google openids:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: is it available for perl/apache too.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [JanRain](http://www.janrain.com/) for the same thing. It is free and integrates with loads of different login providers, such as, Facebook, Twitter, Google, OpenId (generally), yahoo, msn, and many more.
There is code that lets you integrate it with almost any programming language/platform you want.

Comment: JanRain seems flexible, but its not free. and its free signup has only Up to 2,500 users, i guess anually.

Answer (score 1):

try this sample in CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/OpenIdFormsAuth.aspx

It worked fine with me.

Comment: I got it working long back with pure perl solution. will post the sample code in a few days.